# No wireless icon with Ubuntu 14.04 LiveCD

Tags: wireless, system-installation

I am currently a Windows 8.1 user. However, I have used Ubuntu before in the 12.04 version and i really enjoyed it.

Anyway, I have put the ISO onto a USB drive to use to install ubuntu on my laptop. However, when I use the live CD version, I have no Wireless network symbol.

It is like it wireless doesn't exist.

I have tried searching for a solution for this, however I cannot find any solutions that are as specific to my problem.

I am not sure if it is just because I am using the Live CD version and have not installed it.

But I do not want to replace Windows 8.1 (Genuine) if this situation is not able to be resolved.

```
My Laptop is the Hp pavilion 15 p100na, 
Intel core i7,
1TB Hard drive,
8GB Ram,
Intel HD Graphics 4400
```

I have tried enabling my Broadcom bcm43142 driver that is currently installed (I think its preinstalled because I have windows 8 currently installed) and no changes are made.

There is no wireless switch or anything like that and if possible, I do not want to be taking my laptop apart as I have just bought it and I do not want to risk braking it.

Any thoughts?

My Wireless Info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 08 Apr 2015 17:37 UTC +0000

Booted last: 08 Apr 2015 18:33 UTC +0000

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed, cdrom-detect/try-usb=true, noprompt, floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0, ignore_uuid, boot=casper, quiet, splash, --

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2281]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:c344 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 15d9:0a4f Trust International B.V. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 14109  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
bcma                   52320  0 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19193  3 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth1' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.20.10.3  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::6864:4bff:feec:777b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9351 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8651659 (8.6 MB)  TX bytes:827035 (827.0 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.20.10.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
172.20.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     1      0        0 eth1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth1  [Wired connection 2] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            ipheth
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth1' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         172.20.10.3
    Prefix:          28 (255.255.255.240)
    Gateway:         172.20.10.1

    DNS:             172.20.10.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Etc/UTC (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

eth1      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     D52E980A55E0AC3C372382C
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   16.982129] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 0xA886, rev 0x01 and package 0x08
[   16.982159] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x28, class 0x0)
[   16.982183] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x21, class 0x0)
[   16.982232] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x16, class 0x0)
[   16.982294] bcma: bus0: Core 3 found: UNKNOWN (manuf 0x43B, id 0x368, rev 0x00, class 0x0)
[   16.998052] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
[   17.234006] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   17.430343] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[   18.040837] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   40.281214] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Another way of running Ubuntu, is to install virtual-box into Windows-8. You can then run Ubuntu in virtual-box (i7 cpu has hardware support, so this will run at near 100% efficiency, and at least faster that windows 8).  This has the advantage of allowing you to run both at once. It will also resolve any driver issues that you may have.

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. This should uncover, if the system is generally aware of its wireless network capabilities.

Comment: I have put the information into my topic message,